# iPhone: Unable to Move Application to iPhone

Tags: iphone, testing

Xcode version 3.2.1;  iPhone Software Version  as per Organizer Summary tab: 3.1.2 (7D11)

Device does not appear under Device - 3.1.2 | Debug dropdown in Xcode.  Consequently, unable to Build and Go.

Organizer reports in grey typeface:

Xcode cannot find the software image to install this version

What have I done wrong and how can I correct?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Have you successfully built with this device before?  You have a developer provisioning profile installed on it?

In situations like these, rebooting my iPhone usually fixes it.

Comment: No.
Yes.
Unfortunately, rebooting changes nothing.
Thanks anyhow.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like the OS running in the device is not the same as the one specified in XCode and the version of Xcode that you are running does not support the OS installed in the device. This happened to me before. You might have to update your Xcode and/or device OS.